# linked list creation run-time error

Tags: c, linked-list

When I'm running the following C program for linked list creation in gcc compiler in ubuntu 13.04, I'm getting a message of : Segmentation fault (core dumped) , after the list elements are input from the user , without proceeding further. Kindly help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{

/* creating a singly linked list,displaying its elements and finding the sum and average of its elements and searching a particular element in it */

typedef struct node
{
   int info;
   struct node *next;
}N;


N *ptr,*start,*prev;
int i,n,x;
ptr=NULL;
start=NULL;
prev=NULL;  

printf("Enter the number of list elements:  ");      
scanf("%d",&n); 

prev = (N*)malloc(sizeof(N));
start = (N*)malloc(sizeof(N));                                     

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   ptr= (N*)malloc(sizeof(N));
   prev->next = ptr;
   printf("enter the %dth element\t\n",(i+1));
   scanf("%d",&x);
   ptr->info = x;

   if(start==NULL)
   {
      start=ptr;
      prev=ptr;
      ptr->next = NULL;
   }
   else
   {
      prev=ptr;
   }
}                          /* linked list created consisting of n nodes */


/* finding sum and average*/

int sum=0;
float avg;
ptr=start;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   sum =sum + ptr->info;
   ptr = ptr->next;
}
avg = (float)sum/n;             /* summing and averaging completed */

/* displaying data */

ptr=start;
printf("\n The list elements are :  ");
while(ptr != NULL)
   printf("%d\t",ptr->info);
printf("\n");
printf("The sum of list elements is:  %d",sum);
printf("The average of list elements is:  %f",avg);


return 0;
}
```

Comment: do not cast the result of malloc!

Comment: Use a debugger such as gdb to analyze the core dump / step through the program to see exactly where it crashes and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you meant to do

```
    start = NULL; 
    prev = NULL;
```

at the beginning, and also correct -

```
  prev->next = ptr;
```

to

```
  if (prev != NULL)
      prev->next = ptr;
```

or move it to the else section (before prev = ptr).

This way, the first iteration would make start point to the first element, and the next ones would make the prev element point to the current ptr.

By the way, some linked lists hold a dummy "anchor" element for simpler maintenance, but in your case I see you expect the data to appear from the first element already.

Answer (score 0):

when I strip your code I come to this Seltsamkeit:

```
start = (N*)malloc(sizeof(N));                                     

for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
   if(start==NULL)
```

start can never be NULL in this context

i normally use "head" and "next" for the pointer to the working memory, and "list" as a running pointer to the last element of the list for the really allocated memory-linked-list. the metacode is:

```
list = NULL;
head = NULL;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  next = malloc();
  if (head == NULL) {
    head = next; // setting the first haed;
  } else {
    list->next = next; // attaching to the end
  }
  list = next; // pointing to the last element
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand that if I allocate memory space for the start, it won't point to NULL initially, but to some garbage value. Infact, on removing the memory allocations of prev and start before the for loop,my program started running.       But 'start' and 'prev' are N* pointers just like 'ptr', then why is it that 'ptr' needs memory allocation but 'prev' and 'start' do not ?

Comment: a pointer points to some memory (or to NULL). More than one pointer can point to the SAME memory. memory (real allocated space in the heap of the machine) you get by malloc().

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. But my doubt is that 'start' and 'prev' are not simple pointers, but rather of the structure type and hold element values in the form of prev->info . How can it still work without being dynamically allocated atleast one memory block of size of struct data type ?

Comment: You can have multiple pointers to the same object of type N. What happens is that start and prev start out as NULL, pointing to nowhere, then you allocate space for the first object and put the address in ptr, and then copy that address from there to start/prev, and reuse ptr for allocating the next elements. In other words, The first object is allocated once, and have different pointers holding its address as you go along.

Comment: @Leeor : Thanks Leeor. Your answer tells that if a pointer points to something by virtue of storing the address of that thing, it doesn't need a separate memory block, unless it STORES some elements. This in fact seems a true and key point in the explanation. Well, can you tell me that ->next pointer points to the next node structure or the element in the next node ?

Comment: Even if it stores some elements, as long as it points to an existing object that you previously allocated somehow (even if using a different pointer), the actual data would go to the location where that object is stored. As for the ->next - it's pointing to the next object you allocated. Not sure what's the difference between a "node" or "element", but if you're asking if it points to the structure itself or to the first field in it ("info"), the answer is - both. The structure begins at some address, and the first thing stored there is the first field of that structure.

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to explain with an example - if you allocate the first node object at address 0x1000, then the pointer is just a number that hold the value 0x1000. This "number" can be copied around to other pointers - any pointer with this value can let you access that original node. If you then allocate another at 0x2000, you can put that numerical value in ptr (so it's now said to point to the second element), and also in the "next" pointer inside the first node. That pointer would be physically located within the original node (probably at 0x1004), and have the address 0x2000